# Change date format for http callout

Tags: date

I'm sending an http callout with a body that requires todays date formatted as 'YYYY-MM-DD', does anyone know how I can change the format of the date?  I tried

> Date todaysdate = Date.today();
>   string dateoutput = todaysdate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

Does anyone know how I can do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of getting it. `format()` returns the date Date as a string using the locale of the context user. However, in the US that would be in `dd/mm/yyyy`, which isn't what you're looking for. consequently, I'd recommend the following unless you wanted to use [Date-Time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_methods) methods based on `Now()`.

```
string dateoutput = string.valueOf(year(today())) + '-' + string.valueOf(month(today())) + '-' + string.valueOf(day(today()));
```